# Python Regex to extract email

Tags: regex, string, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am trying to use python to extract the `sentence that contains the email`.

```
sample_str = "This is a random sentence. This one is also random sentence but it contains an email address ---@---.com"
```

All the examples I see extract the email, example:

```
import re
lst = re.findall('\S+@\S+', sample_str)
```

But is there anyway to extract the `sentence that contains the email`. in this case

```
op = "This one is also random sentence but it contains an email address ---@---.com"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indicate where a sentence starts, and in between do not match the end of a sentence.

But this can be tricky, and is definitely not a general solution as a sentence does not have to start with a char `[A-Z]` and might end with a different char than `.` `!` `?`

As an idea for the given example, you might use:

```
(?<!\S)[A-Z](?:(?![!?.](?!\S)).)*[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `[A-Z]` Match a char A-Z
- `(?:(?![!?.](?!\S)).)*` Match any char, except for a `!` `?` or `.` directly followed by a whitespace boundary
- `[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+` Match an email like format

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cRd3qd/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/qkwx5y)

Example

```
import re
 
sample_str = "This is a random sentence. This one is also random sentence but it contains an email address ---@---.com"
lst = re.findall('(?<!\S)[A-Z](?:(?![!?.](?!\S)).)*[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+', sample_str) 
 
print(lst)
```

Output

```
['This one is also random sentence but it contains an email address ---@---.com']
```